# Discrete joint probability of 2 random variables

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Formula for discrete joint probabilities:

$$
H(X, Y)=-\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m p\left(x_i, y_j\right) \log p\left(x_i, y_j\right)
$$

I don't really see how the above formula works? How does it also take into account the H(Y|X) on the image below? Isn't the formula just checking that $$
x_i \text { for } i=1, \ldots, n \text { and } y_j \text { for } j=1, \ldots, m
$$ occur at the same time? But the part on the right of Y doesn’t occur together with any x, so how does the formula also count that part? I'm really confused.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue you're describing. What does it mean for a formula to "work"? Note that the formula for joint entropy is just what you get for entropy of the single random variable $U = (X,Y)$ (which you can embed into a $|\mathcal{X}|\cdot |\mathcal{Y}|$ sized alphabet).

Comment: Also note that one does have the standard relations $H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y) - I(X;Y) = H(X) + H(Y|X),$ which are all consistent with the Venn-diagram based intuition.